# Skip $ character from normal text

Tags: mathjax

This is very simple question but I unfortunately didn't get any clue to get rid from this error. I am writing a blog post about jquery ajax where I need to write a symbol $. I am using Mathjax for writing mathematical notation. As I write $ (for example $.getJSON), the Mathjax library decodes this as LaTeX commands. Anybody knows how to skip that $ character so that MathJax library behaves it as normal $?

Comment: I am not sure but did you try putting a \ before $?

Comment: @MMA, when I add \ before $, it diplays the text as \$ not normal $ . But as this is not a math post. I cannot write \[ \$ \]

Comment: Your posting may be off-topic for this site: Mathjax uses TeX-like syntax for some of its expressions, but is not based on TeX and/or LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico then how do I migrate this to the sister site stackoverflow

Comment: @Bibek a moderator can move it when they see the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MathJax does *not* use the single dollar as a delimiter for in-line math (for exactly the reason you indicate), and so your configuration must be explicitly enabling it.  See the [text2jax dpcumentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) for details of how this is done.

You have several options:

1. Remove the configuration that turns on dollar signs for in-line math.  (This won't be good if you have already used them for in-line math in other posts)
2. Enable the `processEscapes` option so that you can use `\$` to get a dollar without it being used as a math delimiter
3. If your blog allows you to enter raw HTML, you could use `<span>$</span>` to prevent MathJax from using the dollar as a delimiter (math can't contain HTML tags, so this dollar will not match up with another one, so won't be used as a delimiter).
4. Put your code examples inside `<pre>` or `<code>` containers, as MathJax (at least by default) doesn't process math within these.  Your configuration may have changed that, however, so check the `skipTags` setting in your configuration.

Any of these should allow you to do what you need.